# How to enable receiving Email Notification for responses to my questions

Tags: feature-request

I am not receiving any notification for the responses to my questions. For some of the questions I had enabled the daily email notification option, but as of now I have not received any.

I am yet to locate any other settings which I probably have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available on your user page, click on your name at the top of the page (not on meta but on askubuntu itself, otherwise you'll sub to questions here, which you probably don't want):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The option is already on for my account. But as because in spite of opting for the daily notification, for the question I asked at AskUbuntu, I didn't get any mail when others responded to my question, although I am getting notifications from Stack Exchange. That is why I thought about asking here.